# pytorch - why to use Tensor.requires_grad_(True) instead of Tensor.requires_grad=True

Tags: pytorch

I'm reading introduction into PyTorch and a bit confused by the `Tensor.requires_grad_(...)` function. Why would one would prefer it instead of just using the setter: `Tensor.requires_grad = ...` ? Setter syntax seems to be more clean and readable. Why to introduce this strange function with this funny underscore suffix?

Comment: Both are equally preferable. `tensor.requires_grad_()` has the default boolean argument set to `True` whereas with `tensor.requires_grad = True`  one has to explicitly set the value. So, the former might be convenient over the latter, sometimes. Also, the trailing `_` (underscore) means that the operation is in-place.